# Elementary os 6 can't sudo apt-get update or any other apt-get

Tags: updates, pantheon-terminal, apt, odin

It returns the following after $ sudo apt update or $ sudo apt-get update or etc...

```
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu focal Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]\
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xanial Release\
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]\
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.\
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.\
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.\
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xanial Release' does not have a Release file.\
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.\
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: That error message is telling you that the PPA that you have just added doesn't work. You still should be able to upgrade other apps.

Comment: @Maccer you are correct thank's. But how i can delete this and not seeing this every time i `sudo apt update` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the two PPAs that are giving you errors, you will need to edit your `sources.list` file.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `sources.list` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor that you prefer. It does not need to be `vi`.</sup>
2. Find the lines that refer to the URLs that are failing
3. Add a `#` to the start of the line, or remove the line completely
4. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

You should not see the error(s) anymore.

If the URLs were not in `sources.list`, then they will be in a `.list` file somewhere inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. This really depends on *how* you added the PPAs to your system to begin with. However, the instructions above apply here as well. Open the file and comment out (or remove) the line.